# Request parameter is not casted to object

Tags: php, rest, api, restler

I have a simple API call, that should accept a request parameter from type `Message`. What I actually get in `$data` is an `array`

```
...

    /**
     * @param Message $data Message to push {@from body}
     *
     * @url POST uploadedFile
     * @return bool
     */
     public function uploadedFile(Message $data) {
        return $this->send(...);
     }

}

class Message
{
     /**
      * @var string */
     private $action;


     /**
      * @var array object to return
      */
     private $parameters;

     /**
      * @var array $type {@type int}
      */
     private $type;

     /**
      * @var string $message {@max 50}
      */
     private $message;
}
```

Here is my json:

```
{
    "action": "test",
    "parameters": [],
    "type": [1,2],
    "message": "test"
}
```

And here is the error I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to FCM::uploadedFile() must be an instance of Message, array given in ... on line 22
```

Comment: make a factory to instantiate a `Message` (add getters and setters) ? What is the actual question here?

Comment: It is an API call, I send a request with the json and it is not recognised as a Message object. Restler usually casts according to the PHP comment parameters.

Comment: looking at the comment and name of the method, are you uploading a file here? also what is the version of restler used?

Comment: It is just a notification, that a file is been uploaded. Resler is version 3 RC6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: For the automatic casting to object to work, the validation for the API class must be switched on. This is done with those two variables:

```
// Excluding classes from validation
Defaults::$autoValidationForbiddenCalls = [ ... ];

// Version from which to auto validate (using PHPDocs)
Defaults::$mandatoryValidationFromVersion = 3;
```

The class I was using was excluded from validation, thus the PHPDoc was ignored.

Comment: Good!, this one will be hard to find externally as we have no clue :)